# Pyspark Columnsimilarities interpretation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was learning about how to use columnsimilarities can someone explain to me the matrix that was generated by the algorithm

lets say in this code

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
rows = sc.parallelize([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)])

# Convert to RowMatrix
mat = RowMatrix(rows)

# Calculate exact and approximate similarities
exact = mat.columnSimilarities()
approx = mat.columnSimilarities(0.05)

# Output
exact.entries.collect()
[MatrixEntry(0, 2, 0.991935352214),
 MatrixEntry(1, 2, 0.998441152599),
 MatrixEntry(0, 1, 0.997463284056)]
```

how can I know which row is most similar given in the maxtrix? like (0,2,0.991935352214) mean that row 0 and row 2 have a result of 0.991935352214? I know that 0 and 2 are i and j the row and columns respectively of the matrix.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

> how can I know which row is most similar given in the maxtrix?

It is **`column`**`Similarities` not **`row`**`Similarities` so it is just not the thing you're looking for.

You could apply it on transposed matrix, but you **really don't want**. Algorithms used here are designed for thin and optimally sparse data. It just won't scale for wide one.

Comment: hmmmm so from the "rows" var, how will you kwow which one in the data are most similar to each other?